# I'm writing a code to check if the elements of an array are sorted or not.In the main function, statement using a ternary operator is giving an error

Tags: c++

So in this question , I am taking an array and check if the array is sorted or not :

```
//A BOOL TYPE FUNCTION THAT I MADE TO CHECK IF THE ARRAY IS SORTED OR NOT :
bool issorted( int a[], int size )

{
   
 if(size ==0 || size ==1 )
       
 return true;

   return a[0]<=a[1]? issorted(a+1,size-1) : false ;

}
```

and finally in main() , I am writing a statement as :

```
{   
  // MAIN PROBLEM LINE : 

  cout<<" the array that you entered is : "<< issorted(p,n)? "sorted":"not sorted "<<endl;
}
```

what i wanted from this cout statement is that i should print "sorted" if the issorted() returns true and else it should print "not sorted". I tried to use ternary operator here but i am getting an error on this line .

So can we not use ternary operators like this?????

(*******the input statements has already been taken care of *****)

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: operator precedence `issorted(p,n)? "sorted":"not sorted "` -> `(issorted(p,n)? "sorted":"not sorted ")`

Comment: Learn a bit more (modern) C++, "C" style arrays are a bit of a mess to work with. E.g.  like this : https://onlinegdb.com/kUo4apZFd

Comment: Side note: `condition ? true_value : false` —> `condition && true_value`. (You can condense the whole function to `return size < 2 || a[0]<=a[1] && issorted(a+1,size-1);`